# TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'remap'

Tags: python, constructor, typeerror

When I run the following command while replicating the late diffusion code, I get a `TypeError` error:

```
python scripts/inpaint.py --indir data/inpainting_examples/ --outdir outputs/inpainting_results
```

The `TypeError` error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scripts/inpaint.py", line 60, in
model = instantiate_from_config(config.model)
File "/root/autodl-tmp/latent-diffusion-main/scripts/ldm/util.py", line 85, in instantiate_from_config
return get_obj_from_str(config["target"])(**config.get("params", dict()))
File "/root/autodl-tmp/latent-diffusion-main/scripts/ldm/models/diffusion/ddpm.py", line 460, in init
self.instantiate_first_stage(first_stage_config)
File "/root/autodl-tmp/latent-diffusion-main/scripts/ldm/models/diffusion/ddpm.py", line 503, in instantiate_first_stage
model = instantiate_from_config(config)
File "/root/autodl-tmp/latent-diffusion-main/scripts/ldm/util.py", line 85, in instantiate_from_config
return get_obj_from_str(config["target"])(**config.get("params", dict()))
File "/root/autodl-tmp/latent-diffusion-main/scripts/ldm/models/autoencoder.py", line 266, in init
super().init(embed_dim=embed_dim, *args, **kwargs)
File "/root/autodl-tmp/latent-diffusion-main/scripts/ldm/models/autoencoder.py", line 39, in init
self.quantize = VectorQuantizer(n_embed, embed_dim, beta=0.25,
TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'remap'
```

Part of the code content is as follows:

```py
def __init__(self,
     ddconfig,
     lossconfig,
     n_embed,
     embed_dim,
     ckpt_path=None,
     ignore_keys=[],
     image_key="image",
     colorize_nlabels=None,
     monitor=None,
     batch_resize_range=None,
     scheduler_config=None,
     lr_g_factor=1.0,
     remap=None,
     sane_index_shape=False, # tell vector quantizer to return indices as bhw
     use_ema=False
     ):
    super().__init__()
    self.embed_dim = embed_dim
    self.n_embed = n_embed
    self.image_key = image_key
    self.encoder = Encoder(**ddconfig)
    self.decoder = Decoder(**ddconfig)
    self.loss = instantiate_from_config(lossconfig)
    self.quantize = VectorQuantizer(n_embed, embed_dim, beta=0.25,remap=remap,sane_index_shape=sane_index_shape)
```

The relevant content of `remap` has been deleted, but an error is still reported. Is there any other solution?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How is the method VectorQuantizer defined? maybe there is something wrong there.